# Why is my MySQL query not ordering correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

In the below query I am trying to order the results by `fc.order` in ascending order:

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS threads_count FROM (
    SELECT fc.uuid AS category_uuid, fc.name, fc.description, fc.order, fc.icon,
           u.uuid AS user_uuid, u.username, u.avatar
    FROM forum_categories AS fc
    INNER JOIN forum_threads AS ft ON fc.id = ft.forum_category_id
    INNER JOIN users as u ON ft.created_by = u.id
    ORDER BY fc.order ASC, ft.created_at DESC
) AS tmp_table GROUP BY category_uuid
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. Below is a screenshot of results from the above query:

[image]

How can I get the results to order by the `order` column?

Comment: Your outer query (the one that produces the final result) does not have `ORDER BY`

Comment: Had to add a second `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thanks guys but I got it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, count(*) AS threads_count FROM (
        SELECT fc.uuid AS category_uuid, fc.name, fc.description, fc.order, fc.icon,
               u.uuid AS user_uuid, u.username, u.avatar
        FROM forum_categories AS fc
        INNER JOIN forum_threads AS ft ON fc.id = ft.forum_category_id
        INNER JOIN users as u ON ft.created_by = u.id
        ORDER BY ft.created_at DESC
    ) AS t1 GROUP BY category_uuid
) as t2 ORDER BY `order`
```

Comment: You don't need nested queries here, it not only makes the query less readable, but it also has performance impact. `ORDER BY` in a nested query also makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, count(t1.*) AS threads_count FROM 
 (
        SELECT fc.uuid AS category_uuid, fc.name, fc.description, fc.order, fc.icon,
               u.uuid AS user_uuid, u.username, u.avatar
        FROM forum_categories AS fc
        INNER JOIN forum_threads AS ft ON fc.id = ft.forum_category_id
        INNER JOIN users as u ON ft.created_by = u.id    
 ) AS tmp_table t1 
GROUP BY category_uuid
ORDER BY t1.order ASC, t1.created_at DESC
```

Comment: It's not obvious why you still need a nested query.